# With openapi-generator, how do you generate a default value for a set

Tags: java, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

If i define a property like this:

```
  scopes:
    type: array
    default: []
    items:
       type: string
```

The generated property is an ArrayList

```
  @JsonProperty("scopes")
  @Valid
  private List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, if I want a set and use

```
uniqueItems: true
```

I don't get a default value

```
  @JsonProperty("scopes")
  @Valid
  private Set<String> scopes;
```

How can I get the following?

```
  @JsonProperty("scopes")
  @Valid
  private Set<String> scopes = new LinkedHashSet();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not currently get your desired output.

That's because it is currently not implemented in OpenAPI Generator. From OpenAPI Generator's `toArrayDefaultValue` source code ([source](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/a67e07e132a74cd5a1063c97ef665ec618bdd692/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/AbstractJavaCodegen.java#L1148C24-L1148C24)):

```java
    } else if (cp.isArray && cp.getUniqueItems()) { // set
        // TODO
        return null;
```

Your best option might be to open an issue or even better a PR for this topic in the [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) project. An alternative, less easy way to get your desired output might be to use OpenAPI Generator's [templating](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating/) feature to override the computed default values by a hard-coded string like "new HashSet<>()".

Comment: Thanks, I actually asked Chat GPT about this and go the same reply... :D